# What is the difference between lm(data~time) and tslm(data~trend)

Tags: r, regression, time-series, forecasting

I observed that the results for both methods are different. Why is this? I know what is going on on `lm`, but can't figure out what happens under the hood at `tslm`.

```
> library(forecast)
> set.seed(2)
> tts <- ts(100*runif(1200)+seq(1:1200)*0.1, frequency=12, start=c(2000,1))
> lm(tts~time(tts))

Call:
lm(formula = tts ~ time(tts))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)    time(tts)  
  -2400.365        1.225  

> tslm(tts~trend)

Call:
tslm(formula = tts ~ trend)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        trend  
    48.9350       0.1021
```

Comment: Have you noticed that 12 * 0.1021 = 1.225?

Comment: Usually, values of time series data are autocorrelated (i.e., dependent). This violates assumption of independency which is needed to carry out linear regression (`lm`) correctly. Thus `lm` is not an appropriate method for autocorrelated.
Quick search on *google* resulted in this link https://www.otexts.org/fpp/4/8 where you can find more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the following three commands:

```
predict(lm(tts~time(tts)))
predict(tslm(tts~time(tts)))
all.equal(predict(lm(tts~time(tts))), predict(tslm(tts~trend)))
```

You will convince yourself that they are identical. if the outputs are identical, then the X variable of the lm regression, i.e.

```
time(tts)
```

must be a linear transformation of

```
trend
```

The easiest guess:

```
tmp <- time(tts)*12
lm(tts~tmp)
```

Has the same coefficient as the tslm coefficient. So trend is just

```
12*time(tts)
```

I.e. trend is the (integer) count of the time passed since year 0, in months. time(tts) is the count of the time passed since year 0, in years.